# Performance issues with Kendo Grid (HTML5)

Tags: javascript, html, performance, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

**Scenario**: I am using Kendo grid (HTML5). To populate the grid client first makes a call to server to fetch the data, once it receives the data then it do some processing on client & then fills the grid.

I am facing severe performance issues with the grid. Grid is only having around 3000 records. But as soon as it populates the data into the grid the browser memory shoots up by more than 400 MB. I want to find out why memory consumption increases so much? Grid has only 5 columns. I have following questions.

1. How can I find out where it is consuming memory? I tried using google chrome in built profiling tool but I could not find any easy way which can clearly show me who is consuming the memory. Is there any better tool to find out this? I am looking for a tool like Red Gate profile .Net profiler.
2. I want to find out why does it takes so much time to render the data. Is there any tool which can tell me which function/line is time consuming?

Atul Sureka

Comment: Do you need all 3000 records being presented on the screen at once? If not have you looked at either using the virtualization or paging settings both client and server. Having experienced this issue before the spike will be purely down to the number of elements `rows/columns` being generated as part of data being loaded up e.g.. 3000 * 5 = 15000 columns and then when you add in all the span tags and any client templating buttons etc. you could be looking at 20K elements trying to be rendered . If you are able to provide a fiddle or dojo that will help to give you tips on improving performance.

Answer (score 2):

Loading 3000 records is the problem. In my experience, you shouldn't load more than 1000 records at a time, but mileage varies because there are many factors that affect network performance and rendering speed.

To solve your problem, you should configure paging on the client **and** the server. This is a common issue and a common solution. On your Kendo UI Datasource object, simply set `serverPaging: true` and the number of items per page `pageSize: 1000`.

```
var ds = new kendo.data.DataSource({
  // other implementation details left out for brevity
  serverPaging: true,
  pageSize: 1000
});
```

Once you do this, the data source will send additional parameters to your server on a request. You must be prepared to handle these parameters. It will send `top`, which refers to the number of records to send back in the response, and `skip`, which indicates the number of records to skip from the start of the dataset. For instance, if you wanted page 3 of a 3000 record dataset at 1000 records per page, the grid would send `skip: 2000`, `top: 1000`.

I don't know what your implementation server-side is, but it's rather trivial to do. Note that you **must** return your data from the server wrapped in an object with two keys, `data` and `total`. This is by convention in Kendo UI. Data is obviously the array of records, and total is the number of records in the array. You can change these defaults within the data source's `schema`, if needed.

Additionally, on the client, you need to tell the grid to expect paging. You can customize the way paging looks by modifying underlying parameters.

```
var grid = $('#grid').kendoGrid({
  // other implementation details left out for brevity
  datasource: ds,
  pageable: {
    numeric: false,
    refresh: true
  }
});
```